# Reading specific registers with seq_file : Device Driver

Tags: c, linux-device-driver

I have a very simple modified driver to write to specific registers. I pass the value and the register I intend to write to. IE: 0x00000008 2, read as write 8 to register (base_addr + 2*4).

This works and was relatively straight forward to implement because the driver automatically receives an input buffer.

Now since in order to read I have to use the seq_file I'm not sure how to pass the register that I would like to read from... The augmented device driver I'm using is posted below.

Is there a way to pass the register value and then using ioread32(base_addr + register)? How can I use copy_from_user in this function where my only inputs are the seq_file?

Usage Example (altered ioread32 to be base_addr+2):

```
$ sudo echo "0x00001233 2" > /proc/accelerator                                  
$ cat /proc/accelerator                                                         
0x1233
$
```

Dev Driver Code:

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <asm/uaccess.h>    /* Needed for copy_from_user */
#include <asm/io.h>         /* Needed for IO Read/Write Functions */
#include <linux/proc_fs.h>  /* Needed for Proc File System Functions */
#include <linux/seq_file.h> /* Needed for Sequence File Operations */
#include <linux/platform_device.h>  /* Needed for Platform Driver Functions */
#include <linux/slab.h> /*for kmalloc and kfree */
#include <linux/vmalloc.h>

/* Define Driver Name */
#define DRIVER_NAME "accelerator"


unsigned long *base_addr;   /* Vitual Base Address */
struct resource *res;       /* Device Resource Structure */
unsigned long remap_size;   /* Device Memory Size */

/* Write operation for /proc/accelerator
 * -----------------------------------
 *  When user cat a string to /proc/accelerator file, the string will be stored in
 *  const char __user *buf. This function will copy the string from user
 *  space into kernel space, and change it to an unsigned long value.
 *  It will then write the value to the register of accelerator controller,
 *  and turn on the corresponding LEDs eventually.
 */
 static ssize_t proc_accelerator_write(struct file *file, const char __user * buf,
                  size_t count, loff_t * ppos)
  {
      //Allocate
      char * myaddr_phrase;
      char * pEnd;
      char *buffer = vzalloc(count);
      myaddr_phrase = buffer;
      u32 myaddr_value;
       u32 myreg_value;

      //Copy Data 
      if (count < 22) {
          if (copy_from_user(myaddr_phrase, buf, count))
              return -EFAULT;

         //myaddr_phrase[count] = '\0';
     printk("count = %d\n", count);
     printk("%s\n",myaddr_phrase);
      }
    // Use strtol to parse input
    /* http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtol/ */
         myaddr_value = simple_strtoul(myaddr_phrase, &pEnd, 0);
     printk("myaddr_value = %08x\n", myaddr_value);
     pEnd = strsep(&myaddr_phrase," ");
     myreg_value = simple_strtoul(myaddr_phrase,&pEnd ,0);
     printk("myreg_value = %08x\n", myreg_value);
     printk("final_value = %08x\n", (base_addr + (myreg_value)));
     printk("mult_val = %08x\n", (myreg_value));
     wmb();
     iowrite32(myaddr_value, (base_addr + (myreg_value)));
     return count;
 }

 /* Callback function when opening file /proc/accelerator
  * ------------------------------------------------------
  *  Read the register value of accelerator controller, print the value to
  *  the sequence file struct seq_file *p. In file open operation for /proc/accelerator
  *  this callback function will be called first to fill up the seq_file,
  *  and seq_read function will print whatever in seq_file to the terminal.
  */
 static int proc_accelerator_show(struct seq_file *p, void *v)
 {
     u32 accelerator_value;
     accelerator_value = ioread32(base_addr+2);
     seq_printf(p, "0x%x\n", accelerator_value);
     return 0;
 }

 /* Open function for /proc/accelerator
   * ------------------------------------
   *  When user want to read /proc/accelerator (i.e. cat /proc/accelerator), the open function 
   *  will be called first. In the open function, a seq_file will be prepared and the 
   *  status of accelerator will be filled into the seq_file by proc_accelerator_show function.
   *
   *p 69
    int (*open) (struct inode *, struct file *);
    Though this is always the first operation performed on the device file, the driver
    is not required to declare a corresponding method. If this entry is NULL, opening
    the device always succeeds, but your driver isn’t notified.

    Open described on p76
   */
 static int proc_accelerator_open(struct inode *inode, struct file *file)
  {
      unsigned int size = 16;
      char *buf;
      struct seq_file *m;
      int res;

      buf = (char *)kmalloc(size * sizeof(char), GFP_KERNEL);
      if (!buf)
          return -ENOMEM;

      res = single_open(file, proc_accelerator_show, NULL);

      if (!res) {
          m = file->private_data;
          m->buf = buf;
          m->size = size;
      } else {
          kfree(buf);
      }

      return res;
  }

  /* File Operations for /proc/accelerator */
  static const struct file_operations proc_accelerator_operations = {
      .open = proc_accelerator_open,
      .read =  seq_read,
      .write = proc_accelerator_write,
      .llseek = seq_lseek,
      .release = single_release
  };
  /*
int (*open) (struct inode *, struct file *);
Though this is always the first operation performed on the device file, the driver
is not required to declare a corresponding method. If this entry is NULL, opening
the device always succeeds, but your driver isn’t notified.

ssize_t (*read) (struct file *, char __user *, size_t, loff_t *);
Used to retrieve data from the device. A null pointer in this position causes the
readsystem call to fail with-EINVAL(“Invalid argument”). A nonnegative return
value represents the number of bytes successfully read (the return value is a
“signed size” type, usually the native integer type for the target platform)

ssize_t (*write) (struct file *, const char __user *, size_t, loff_t *);
Sends data to the device. IfNULL, -EINVALis returned to the program calling the
writesystem call. The return value, if nonnegative, represents the number of
bytes successfully written.

loff_t (*llseek) (struct file *, loff_t, int);
Thellseek method is used to change the current read/write position in a file, and
the new position is returned as a (positive) return value. Theloff_tparameter is
a “long offset” and is at least 64 bits wide even on 32-bit platforms. Errors are
signaled by a negative return value. If this function pointer isNULL, seek calls will
modify the position counter in thefilestructure (described in the section “The
file Structure”) in potentially unpredictable ways.

int (*release) (struct inode *, struct file *);
This operation is invoked when thefilestructure is being released. Likeopen,
releasecan beNULL.
*
  */


  /* Shutdown function for accelerator
   * -----------------------------------
   *  Before accelerator shutdown, turn-off all the leds
  */
 static void accelerator_shutdown(struct platform_device *pdev)
 {
    iowrite32(0, base_addr);
 }

 /* Remove function for accelerator
  * ----------------------------------
  *  When accelerator module is removed, turn off all the leds first,
  *  release virtual address and the memory region requested.
  */
 static int accelerator_remove(struct platform_device *pdev)
 {
     accelerator_shutdown(pdev);

     /* Remove /proc/accelerator entry */
     remove_proc_entry(DRIVER_NAME, NULL);

     /* Release mapped virtual address */
     iounmap(base_addr);

     /* Release the region */
     release_mem_region(res->start, remap_size);

     return 0;
 }

 /* Device Probe function for accelerator
  * ------------------------------------
  *  Get the resource structure from the information in device tree.
  *  request the memory region needed for the controller, and map it into
  *  kernel virtual memory space. Create an entry under /proc file system
  *  and register file operations for that entry.
  */
 static int accelerator_probe(struct platform_device *pdev)
 {

     struct proc_dir_entry *accelerator_proc_entry;
     int ret = 0;
    printk(KERN_ALERT "Probing\n");
     res = platform_get_resource(pdev, IORESOURCE_MEM, 0);
     if (!res) {
         dev_err(&pdev->dev, "No memory resource\n");
         return -ENODEV;
     }

     remap_size = res->end - res->start + 1;
     if (!request_mem_region(res->start, remap_size, pdev->name)) {
         dev_err(&pdev->dev, "Cannot request IO\n");
         return -ENXIO;
     }

     base_addr = ioremap(res->start, remap_size);
     if (base_addr == NULL) {
         dev_err(&pdev->dev, "Couldn't ioremap memory at 0x%08lx\n",
             (unsigned long)res->start);
         ret = -ENOMEM;
         goto err_release_region;
     }

     accelerator_proc_entry = proc_create(DRIVER_NAME, 0, NULL,
                        &proc_accelerator_operations);
     if (accelerator_proc_entry == NULL) {
         dev_err(&pdev->dev, "Couldn't create proc entry\n");
         ret = -ENOMEM;
         goto err_create_proc_entry;
     }

     printk(KERN_INFO DRIVER_NAME " probed at VA 0x%08lx\n",
            (unsigned long) base_addr);
     printk(KERN_ALERT "Goodbye, probe\n"); 

     return 0;

  err_create_proc_entry:
     iounmap(base_addr);
  err_release_region:
     release_mem_region(res->start, remap_size);

     return ret;
 }

 /* device match table to match with device node in device tree */
 /*
 https://lwn.net/Articles/448502/
 */
 static const struct of_device_id accelerator_of_match[] = {
     {.compatible = "PCA,bitSplitter"},
     {},
 };

 MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE(of, accelerator_of_match);

 /* platform driver structure for accelerator driver */
 /*
 Platform devices are represented by the struct, and is found in <linux/platform_device.h>
 at minimum probe() and remove() must be supplied, the others have to do with power management 
 https://lwn.net/Articles/448499/
 */
 static struct platform_driver accelerator_driver = {
     .driver = {
            .name = DRIVER_NAME,
            .owner = THIS_MODULE,
            .of_match_table = accelerator_of_match},
     .probe = accelerator_probe,
     .remove = accelerator_remove,
     .shutdown = accelerator_shutdown
};

 /* Register accelerator platform driver */
 /*
   Helper macro for drivers that don't do
 * anything special in module init/exit.  This eliminates a lot of
 * boilerplate.  Each module may only use this macro once, and
 * calling it replaces module_init() and module_exit()
 *
 * Platform drivers are for HW that will not dynamically come and go into a Linux system, 
 * such as the video and audio controllers in a tablet.  In makes sense to statically pull 
 * in those code necessary through the __initcall magic discussed above.  
 *
 * http://henryomd.blogspot.com/2014/11/linux-kernel-startup.html
 */
 module_platform_driver(accelerator_driver);

 /* Module Informations */
 /*
 Discussed in 2.6 Preliminaries 
 */
 MODULE_AUTHOR("Digilent, Inc.");
 MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
 MODULE_DESCRIPTION(DRIVER_NAME ": accelerator driver (Simple Version)");
 MODULE_ALIAS(DRIVER_NAME);
```

Comment: You have to read whatever you want to a temporary buffer and then print to a sequential file via `seq_printf()` for example. To pass register to read from you have to provide an interface. If you want to do this through file system you need at least two files to have.